# Make a div draggable and parent div moves along

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have:

```
 <div id=\"car-edit-div\">
    <div id=\"hide-car-edit-div\">
        <p class=\"popup-bar-p\">Add sectors to image.</p>
        <div id=\"hide-car-edit\" onclick=\"javascript:$('#car-edit-div').hide();\"></div>
    </div>
    <div id=\"image-edit-div\"></div>
    <map id=\"map\" name=\"image-edit\"></map>
    <div id=\"edit-zones-div\">
        <div id=\"edit-zones-list-div\">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I want that you can drag from `#hide-car-edit-div` and `#car-edit-div` with whole content will move along. And all these elements will move as one( appearance doesnt change ).

I found that I can do it like this, but It doesnt work as I wanted, you can drag it from any place inside of `#car-edit-div`.

```
$('#car-edit-div').draggable({ handler: '#hide-car-edit-div'});
```

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in syntax.

```
$('#car-edit-div').draggable({ handle: '#hide-car-edit-div'});
```